# Breadth first search for an 8 puzzle

Tags: algorithm, optimization, time-complexity, breadth-first-search

I was asked to implement a breadth first search for solving an eight-puzzle, representing each of its states with a vector with 9 elements, storing the tile number (or 0 for the gap) as the the data in the position.

For example `[1, 3, 4, 2, 8, 0, 6, 7, 5]` represents:

```
1 3 4
2 8 # <- Gap here
6 7 5
```

My pseudo-coded  algorithm so far is:

```
startnode.configuration = start
startnode.parent        = NIL
startnode.distance      = 0
startnode.state         = DISCOVERED
nodes_to_process        = queue {}
nodes_to_process.enqueue(startnode)
while nodes_to_process is not empty
    node = nodes_to_process.dequeue()
    for each neighbour in NEIGHBOURS(node)
        if neighbour.state == UNDISCOVERED
            neighbour.distance = node.distance + 1
            neighbour.parent   = node
            neighbour.state    = DISCOVERED
```

The problem with this is: when I add a new neighbour how do I keep track of which nodes have been assigned as visited? Should I compare the state arrays one by one (preferaby having an ordered set of them), or is there a more refined approach, where I can skip this array-comparison step? Is the best algorithm complexity O(N * ln N) for the search?

Comment: You can use a list with discovered and add after discovery, than you can check if it''s in the list with discovered nodes.

Comment: @SvenB Yes, but since an eight-puzzle can have 181440 different elements, this would be rather slow (O(181440 * 181440) with simple search, O(181440 * ln(181440)) with an ordered list)

Comment: you can add a property to the nodes (visited)

Comment: @SvenB Unfortunately, simply doing that wouldn't help in this problem either, since finding the new neighbours would still only produce me an array, and no information about the state.

Comment: You check all connecting nodes of the current node, first check if already visited, if not mark as visited.

Comment: @SvenB I am discovering the connections during the search, so I cannot possibly know the state before the visit.

Comment: Set the initial State to not visited

Comment: (The most important line of any question is the title: yours' contains a typo.)

Comment: What's the issue with the current code? It looks like you are saving discovered, distance and parent properties on the nodes.